# regular expression achieve two goals : replacement and removal

Tags: regex, perl

I couldn't set a better title for the question but my problem is this:

given a line of the form :

```
int a,b,var1,var2;
```

I need to convert it to a line of the form

```
s(a);s(b);s(var1);s(var2);
```

so far I have this:

```
s/\b(\w)[,;]/s\(\1\);/g
```

but it only converts it to

```
int s(a);s(b);s(var1);s(var2);
```

I need to not see the `int` part. Can this be done using only one regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non catching part of your regular expression together with making it optional, as in the below example:

```
$_ = "int a,b,var1,var2;";

s/(?:^\w+\s+)?([^;,]+)[;,]/s(\1);/g;

print $_
```

<sup>output</sup>

```
s(a);s(b);s(var1);s(var2);
```